# android TabHost Crystal style?

Tags: android, tabs

I've tried to make my app Tabs appear like Crystal with lighting line , for example like Sony Xperia update center app (tabs)

but i failed , can i do this tabs style throw Xml style ? or i have create background drawables as images and set them into xml selector ?

this picture show you what i mean

[image]

is there any simple way to do like this tabs style ?

Sorry for my english but i hope you got it